# To what does SPIR-V get compiled to?

Tags: gpu, shader, spir-v

SPIR-V -???-> GPU native

https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2016-vulkan-devday-uk/3-Intro-to-spir-v-shaders.pdf
Mentioned it's a "IHV Compiler" but I can't figure out what that is.
I presume it's a vendor (Nvidia/AMD/intel) specific compiler. Where can I find more information on SPIR-V to native (GPU) machine format compilers?

Comment: Why does there have to be a ??? between these two? And what would you do with such information anyway? You can't control it or affect the results without vendor-specific extensions. And if such extensions exist, they'll tell you how they work.

Comment: I've no idea what happens there. GLSL gets compiled to SPIR-V with glslangvalidator. But does SPIR-V use to get to the native gpu format?

Comment: You're missing the point of my question: what does it matter? You have some SPIR-V code, and you hand it off to an API to get a shader module/whatever that does what the SPIR-V specification says that the given SPIR-V does. Exactly how that process works is irrelevant; it's beyond your control outside of any vendor-specific extensions.

Comment: I'm trying to fuzz gpu instructions.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have my answer, instructions get compiled by the driver at load time. AMD does provide the ISA https://gpuopen.com/documentation/amd-isa-documentation/
But Nvidia doesn't.

Comment: What does "fuzz" mean in this context? Even if you know the ISA, that doesn't mean you get to feed the GPU your code. Not unless there's a vendor extension to let you do that.

Comment: As far as I know you can feed bytecode to AMD cards nowadays... nvidia not so much but if you're willing to do some reverse engineering you might find a way.